# Forcing Gitlab CI pipeline status

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have the following Gitlab CI pipeline :
--- job 1 ---- job 2 ---- job 3

I implemented a workflow where even if job 1 fails, job 2 runs and if it succeeds job 3 also runs.
Problem is, the pipeline shows up as failed because job 1 failed ( even though job 2 and 3 succeeded ). I can't allow the failure of job 1.

Is there anyway I can instruct the pipeline to have the same status as a specific job or force its success even though only one job failed ?